# When making histogram Matplotlib Python the x-values and y-values are interchanged?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

After I created a simple series, I wanted to create a histogram by doing this:

```
data = np.array([3368, 4043])
s = pd.Series(data,index=['FEMALE','MALE'])

s.hist()
```

However, the histogram will look like this:

[image]

This is not correct, as I want the variable sex on the x-axis and I want the values of 3368 and 4043 on the y-axis. How do I fix this?

Comment: `s.plot.bar()`?

Comment: Owh stupid, now I searched for difference between histogram and barplot and now I get it...